# Regex match dates with special characters prefix

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code:

```
var splitter = (filterValue.length > 0 ? filterValue.match(/^\s*(<|>)?\s*(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})\s*\-?\s*(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})?\s*$/).slice(1) : '');
```

Where `filterValue` could be:

```
01/01/2013

> 01/01/2013

< 01/01/2013

01/01/2013 - 01/01/2013
```

And then I split these into chunks like:

```
    var string1 = (splitter.length > 0 ? splitter[0] : '');
    var string2 = (splitter.length >= 2 ? splitter[1] : '');
var string3 = (splitter.length >= 3 ? splitter[2] : '');
var string4 = (splitter.length < 4 ? splitter[3] : '');
```

`string1` would be either `'', '>', '<', ''` for the above examples.

`string2` would always be the first date

`string3` would be either `''` or `'-'` if the dash is present between two dates

`string4` would be the last date.

However I can't get the last scenario to work. So presume I have a problem in my regex for handling this. Can anyone see the problem?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7LR49/1/

I'm getting:

```
undefined
01/01/2013
01/01/2013
undefined
```

When I should be getting:

```
undefined
01/01/2013
-
01/01/2013
```

and doing a console on splitter shows:

`[undefined, "01/01/2013", "01/01/2013"]`

So the last 3rd key isn't actual being picked up by the regex. And instead getting the 4th in its place.

Comment: I don't see how that particular error results from this code. Could you provide a fiddle that exhibits your error?

Comment: Added a fiddle with examples of what I'm getting and what I should be getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of fixes:

- Your regex was not capturing the dash as third group. So I changed it.

From: `/^\s*(<|>)?\s*(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})\s*\-?\s*(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})?\s*$/`
To....: `/^\s*(<|>)?\s*(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})\s*(\-)?\s*(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})?\s*$/`
Changed: `.................................^..^`

- And your condition was not evluating to `true` so you would ignore the last group's value:

From: `var string4 = (splitter.length < 4 ? splitter[3] : '');`
To....: `var string4 = (splitter.length < 5 ? splitter[3] : '');`
Changed: `..............................^`

Output now:

```
undefined
01/01/2013
-
01/01/2013
```

Your fiddle, updated: http://jsfiddle.net/7LR49/2/

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
function getMatches(string, regex, index) {
    index || (index = 1); // default to the first capturing group
    var matches = [];
    var match;
    while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
        matches.push(match[index]);
    }
    return matches;
  }
  var str = "> 01/01/2013 - 02/01/2013";
  var regex = /\b(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)\b/g;
  var matches = getMatches(str, regex, 1);
  alert(matches[0]);
  alert(matches[1]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
01/01/2013
02/01/2013
```

The method is taken from [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14210948/1057429)

Comment: I need the `<` and `-`

Comment: @Cameron in that case: `var arr = str.split(/\s+/g);` seems to do the job